# Ngnix settings can not change the default index.html

Tags: nginx

I config a static site via nginx, and include my settings under conf.d directory. listen port 80.

But I found when I request the url, nginx always redirect the default page /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

My configuration does seem work, for all access logs were written to my access log settings, and if I change index.html to some other name(i.html for example) in my directory, and request url mysite.com/i.html, I can access the correct page.

So, it seems that nginx redirect all index.html to the default one.

I tried change default port/server name/root and annotate the default settings, even close selinux, all above doesn't work, it really make me mad.

Can anyone help me?

I'm using nginx version 1.10.2, on CentOS 7.2

and following is my site settings:

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream blog {
    server 0.0.0.0:80; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first) 
}
# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80 default_server;
    listen      [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name mysite.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    access_log  /var/log/blog/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/blog/error.log;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / { try_files $uri @blog; }
    location @blog{
    root /home/work/projects/blog/public/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 120s;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 120s;
    }
}
```

and the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is

```
server {
    # listen       8000 default_server;
    # listen       [::]:8000 default_server;
    # server_name  not;
    # root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    # include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    # location / {
    # }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri @blog;
}
location @blog{
    root /home/work/projects/blog/public/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 120s;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 120s;
}
```

The lack of a `root` directive means that the first `try_files` will look for files in the default location.

All you need is `root` and `index` directives within the `server` context:

For example:

```
root /home/work/projects/blog/public;
index index.html index.htm;

location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.